# Add a category without data in it to a plot in seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am making plotting some data as a catplot like this:

```
ax = sns.catplot(x='Kind', y='VAF', hue='Sample', jitter=True, data=df, legend=False)
```

The trouble is that some of the categories of `'VAF'` contain no data, and the corresponding label is not added to the plot. Is there a way to retain the label but just not plot any points for it?

Here is a reproducible example to help explain:

```
x=pd.DataFrame({'Data':[1,3,4,6,3,2],'Number':['One','One','One','One','Three','Three']})
plt.figure()
ax = sns.catplot(x='Number', y='Data', jitter=True, data=x)
```

In this plot you can see that on the x-axis, samples One and Three are displayed. But imagine that there is also a sample Two that just had no data points in it. How can I display One, Two, and Three on the x-axis?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what *"some of the categories of 'VAF' contain no data"* actually means in terms of data/code? Also, which label do you mean?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added and example that hopefully helps.

Comment: The answer got a bit more complicated than anticipated due to a small bug in current versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Order parameter

Of course one would need to know which categories are expected. Given a list of expected categories, one can use the `order` parameter to supply the expected categories.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[1,3,4,6,3,2],
                   'Number':['One','One','One','One','Three','Three']})

exp_cats = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

ax = sns.stripplot(x='Number', y='Data', jitter=True, data=df, order=exp_cats)

plt.show()
```

[image]

## Alternatives

The above works with matplotlib 2.2.3, but not with 3.0. It works again with the current development version (hence 3.1). For the moment, there are the following alternatives:

#### A. Looping over categories

Given a list of expected categories, one can just loop over them and plot a scatter of each category.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[1,3,4,6,3,2],
                   'Number':['One','One','One','One','Three','Three']})

exp_cats = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

for i, cat in enumerate(exp_cats):
    cdf = df[df["Number"] == cat]
    x = np.zeros(len(cdf))+i+.2*(np.random.rand(len(cdf))-0.5)
    plt.scatter(x, cdf["Data"].values)
plt.xticks(range(len(exp_cats)), exp_cats)

plt.show()
```

#### B. Map categories to numbers.

You can map the expected categories to numbers and plot numbers instead of categories.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[1,3,4,6,3,2],
                   'Number':['One','One','One','One','Three','Three']})

exp_cats = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

df["IntNumber"] = df["Number"].map(dict(zip(exp_cats, range(len(exp_cats)))))

plt.scatter(df["IntNumber"] + .2*(np.random.rand(len(df))-0.5), df["Data"].values,
            c = df["IntNumber"].values.astype(int))
plt.xticks(range(len(exp_cats)), exp_cats)

plt.show()
```

#### C. Appending missing categories to the dataframe

Finally you may append `nan` values to the dataframe to make sure each expected category appears in it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data':[1,3,4,6,3,2],
                   'Number':['One','One','One','One','Three','Three']})

exp_cats = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

dfa = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Data':[np.nan]*len(exp_cats), 'Number':exp_cats}))

ax = sns.stripplot(x='Number', y='Data', jitter=True, data=dfa, order=exp_cats)

plt.show()
```

Comment: one possible addition to this already very detailed answer - if you make the `'Number'` column Categorical (i.e. `df['Number'] = pd.Categorical(df['Number'], categories=['One', 'Two', 'Three'])`) then you can simply do the plotting as specified - `ax = sns.stripplot(x='Number', y='Data', jitter=True, data=df)` - with the category added as required

Comment: (tested in matplotlib 2.1.0)